# Sentence with two PPs, without recursive embedding of either in the other

Tags: syntax-trees, prepositions, embedding, recursion

I'm having some difficulty with finding an example of an English sentence which includes two consecutive prepositional phrases without embedding. Would "We ran off into the sunset" qualify?

Comment: Does "this train goes from London to Edinburgh" count?

Comment: Yes, or any example giving a path which is characterized by saying what points are on the path.  "Over the river, through the woods, up the trail, past the statue, ..."

Comment: A case could be made for "into the sunset" being a complement in  the matrix PP.